# Decent Playing Strength Chess Engine

Tags: engines, analysis, tactics, evaluation

I'd like to make a chess program to play decent strength chess (say around 2100 ELO). What are the factors in Eval & techniques in Search that one would consider to achieve that rating?

Answer (score 1):

- Bug-free material evaluation
- Null move heuristic
- Common knowledge such as rook on the seventh rank, king safety, weak squares etc
- Q-search
- Transposition table
- Killer heuristic
- Efficient move generator
- Nega-max
- Iterative deepening
- Aspiration windows

Comment: Does the choice of board representation really matters with the pure playing strength of the chess engine?

Comment: @techcraver Of course it does!!!! Part of "efficient move generator" in my bullet points.

Comment: I know bitboards are the way to go at the moment. But 0x88 would be a middle ground for a chess engine that I expect not to go more than 2500 ELO playing strength?

Comment: @techcraver I only used bitboards, and I think it's most common. Not sure about 0x88.